# Install "dev" build of Android app along side market version

Tags: android

I just released my first Android Application through the market. I'm currently working on some new features for the next release and would like to install this "dev build" on my phone, without uninstalling the "production" version (among other things, this will stop future updates from the Market).

I'm especially interested in this because I'd like to give the APK to friends / "beta-testers" to try, but I don't want them to uninstall the released application first.

Is there anyway to have on one device two applications: "App (via market)" and "App (DEV)"

Would this involve using a different signing key or modifying the manifest in someway?

Thanks!

Comment: For beta testing I'd suggest you tell your friends to install current version from App Market and send them signed .apk:s for development versions (the ones you're about to publish once ready). And no, it's not possible to have same application installed with different keys (at least on stock Android AFAIK).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply rename the package, so both apps are installed.

You need to change the package name in the manifest as well as in the source folder. Use Eclipse's refactoring for it and it will be done in a minute.

They don't need to be signed with the same key.

Comment: But can they be signed with the same key?

Comment: By "rename the package" do you mean change "com.example.myapp" to "com.example.myappdev"?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: After doing this I get lots of R cannot be resolve to a variable. I think there might be more involved than just changing the manifest :/

Comment: You need to rename it within Eclipse, so it updates all references, not just change the manifest.

Comment: I need to step back and think about this. I have no idea what google was thinking. Eclipse (Android ADT) does not refactor my source very well at all - I refactored the package name from com.test to com.test.dev and that just broke everything. To be honest its ridiculous I have to modify the source to run a dev build along side production. On IOS I just modify an environment variable and everything else is automated for me.

Is there nothing similar for android?

Comment: Well, you **can** do is semi-automatically with a script, just replace all occurrences, eg with `find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/com.test/ com.test.dev /' {} \;`

Comment: I had this working a while ago. I'm using product flavors in the build.gradle and have applicationID set to different things. it doesn't work anymore, and claims a duplicate permission for the package name I use for production. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 8):

Using Gradle this is very easy. Here's an excerpt from one of my gradle files:

```
android {
    // ...

    defaultConfig {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "<app name>"
        // ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // ...
        }
        debug {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "<app name> (debug)"
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The key part for allowing another installation is using the `applicationIdSuffix` that is set in the `debug` build. Under the hood this basically does the same thing as proposed in Force's answer; it changes the application id of your app.

Setting the resValue `app_name` allows us to have different app names as well, this makes it much easier to keep track of which installation is which (since both application would get the same name otherwise).

Don't forget to remove the `app_name` from your `strings.xml` and fill in your own app name instead of `<app name>` if you decide to set the app_name in the gradle file like I did above.